# php input file keep inserting into database

Tags: php, database, image, file, input

I have two file input field. I want both of them to be selected to insert into the database. If only one file is selected that will not be inserted into the database....

```
if(isset($_FILES['files'])){
$errors= array();
foreach($_FILES['files']['tmp_name'] as $key => $tmp_name ){
    $file_name = $key.$_FILES['files']['name'][$key];
    $file_size =$_FILES['files']['size'][$key];
    $file_tmp =$_FILES['files']['tmp_name'][$key];
    $file_type=$_FILES['files']['type'][$key];  
    if($file_size > 2097152){
        $errors[]='File size must be less than 2 MB';
    }       
    $query="INSERT into photo (`id`,`name`,`size`,`type`) VALUES('','$file_name','$file_size','$file_type'); ";
    $desired_dir="user_data";
    if(empty($errors)==true){
        if(is_dir($desired_dir)==false){
            mkdir("$desired_dir", 0700);        // Create directory if it does not exist
        }
        if(is_dir("$desired_dir/".$file_name)==false){
            move_uploaded_file($file_tmp,"$desired_dir/".$file_name);
        }else{                                  // rename the file if another one exist
            $new_dir="$desired_dir/".$file_name.time();
             rename($file_tmp,$new_dir) ;               
        }
     mysql_query($query);           
    }else{
            print_r($errors);
    }
}
if(empty($error)){
    echo "Success";
}
}


<form action="" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <input type="file" name="files[]" multiple/>
    <input type="file" name="files[]" multiple/>
    <input  type="submit"  />  
</form>
```

this code run well but keep insert into database when only 1 file is selected. How can I stop inserting into database when only 1 file is selected?? ...

Answer (score 0):

```
            if(isset($_FILES['files'])){
            $errors= array();
             if(count($_FILES['files']['name']) !== 2){
                $errors[]= 'You have to upload two files';
            }
            /**
             * rest of your code
             */
```

Comment: thx abhisek for answer... i wanna user can choose input 2 file or only 1. and when they only chose to input 1 file, other field keep empty and not inserted into database. the problem is when they only choosed 1 file,in databse keep record 2 file

Comment: Please include explanation of what your code does and how it answers the question. If you get a code snippet as an answer, you may not know what to do with it. Answer should give the OP and future visitors guidance on how to debug and fix their problem. Pointing out, what the idea behind your code is, greatly helps in understanding the issue and applying or modifying your solution.

Comment: i wanna upload the file/image into folder and save url/path into database... $query="INSERT into photo (''); ";. this query  will record it into database... but the problem is:  from  2 input field,when i hit submit button with only 1 image and leave 1 field empty,the sql query keep make record into database with 2 row,1 with image details('id(ai)',$file_name,$file_size,.....) which i select and 1 other row is with the same detail but empty result only id(ai) and $file_size =0. i want empty field isnt insert into database>>how? ty